# How to plot by time without time variable in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I have a dataset of four teams who were surveyed every week for 5 weeks. I want to get a line plot of each variable over the 5 weeks, but I don't have a "week" variable to put on the x axis, so I'm not sure how to manipulate my data to get this.

The data I have looks like this (example using 1 variable measured over the 5 weeks):

```
          var_week1   var_week2    var_week3    var_week4    var_week5    
team_a            5         3.2            7          6.4            6
team_b            3           4            4            3            4
team_c          7.6           5          3.8            6            4
team_d            5           3          2.7            4            3
```

I want to get a plot that looks like this, with the week on the x axis and the var value on the y axis (and a line for each team):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "wide to long" problem. A tidyverse solution, assuming your data frame is named `mydata` and has row names as in your example:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "team") %>% 
  gather(Week, Value, -team) %>% 
  mutate(Week = as.numeric(gsub("var_week", "", Week))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Week, Value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = team))
```

Result:

[image]